# Let $f(x) = \exp (x^2 − x + 6)$. Choose Dom(f) so that $f^{−1}$ exists. What is $f^{−1}$ and Dom($f^{−1}$) in your case?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, inverse

I have already got $$y=\exp(x^2-x+16)$$
$$\ln y = x^2-x+6$$
$$\ln x=y^2-y+6$$

I know for getting inverse function we need to solve for $x$, but what should i do in this case?

Comment: First you need to solve $\log y = x^2 -x + 6$ for $x$ to get the inverse function $x(y)$. This is a quadratic equation and can be solved using the standard formula.

Comment: @Winther This is the part I am having trouble on because I do not know how to solve for x in this case.

Comment: Do you know how to solve $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ ? If not then you can [read about it here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation).

Comment: hint:  $y^2-y+6=(y-3)(y+2)$

Comment: is it using the "root = (b^2-4ac)/2 " thing? I know I can only use it when the other side equals 0. So I wasn't sure

Comment: Then just move $\log y$ over to the other side and voila! Note that when we are solving  that equation for $x$ then $y$ is just a constant like $6$.

Comment: Sorry Winther I am still very lost

Comment: The equation $x^2 - x + (6-\log y) = 0$ is a quadratic equation with $a=1$, $b=-1$ and $c = 6-\log y$.

Comment: got it! thank you Winther

Answer (score 0):

(i) We need to solve $$\log y = x^2 - x + 6 \, \Leftrightarrow \, x^2 - x + 6 - \log y = 0.$$ Use the quadratic formula with $a = 1, \, b = -1, \, c = 6 - \log y$.

(ii) For any function $f$, and its inverse $f^{-1}$, we have $\operatorname{dom} f^{-1} = \operatorname{range} f$. This makes sense because the definition of an inverse function is $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$.

Comment: I used the quadratic formula and got two equations for x, do i just switch the xy position to obtain the inverse function?  I have got $x=(1+root(-23+4log 4))/2$, how do i use this result for question asking for domain?

Comment: Your solution is incorrect, it must be a function of $y$. For the domain of the inverse, see point (ii). Also, use \sqrt{t} for $\sqrt t$.